# Date format in elasticsearch-watcher

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-watcher

Im trying to make wacher and i need to compair datetime in document with today-24h. So now i have this code:

```json
"condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.event_time": {
        "lte": "<{now-24h}>"
      }
    }
  }
```

And this doesnt work. I think this is due to the fact that docs have `2022-02-12 00:00:00` format and `"<{now-24h}>"` have `2022-02-15T10:22:59.728Z` format. How can i fix that without changing date format of document?

Comment: Hmm, I am wondering about your mapping could you share with us the mapping of your index ? More specifically the type for the field `event_time` could it be somehting else than `date` or `date_nanos`

Comment: mapping for event_type 

`              
  "event_time" : {
                  "type" : "date",
                  "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
}
`

Comment: When you say it does not work ... How does it manifest? The results you get have an offset, it fail silently? I wonder if using a script in your case could help ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/condition-script.html#accessing-watch-payload

Comment: By the way ... I am not sure where I have read this but I think if the timezone isn't provided they use the timezone of the node processing your request. (I am truly not sure about this tho ... I could not find the source)